# Python socket : Error receive data

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I write a network application. The server has ability to find client base on given subnet. If the client receive authentication message from server, it will respond to server. Everything working good but server, it can't receiver from client.

Client :

```
def ListenServer():
    # Listen init signal from Server to send data

    HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
    PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port

    # UDP Socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    if data == 'Authen':
        SocketConnect(addr[0])

def SocketConnect(HOST):
    # Connect to Server to send data
    print HOST
    PORT = 50008              # The same port as used by the server

    # Create Socket
    print "Create Socket"
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except socket.error, e:
        print "Error creating socket: %s" %e
        sys.exit(1)

    # Connect
    print "Connect"
    try:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error, e:
        print "Connection error: %s" %e
        sys.exit(1)

    # Send Data
    print "Send Data"
    try:
        s.sendall('Hello, world')
    except socket.error, e:
        print "Error sending data: %s" % e
        sys.exit(1)


    # Close Socket
    s.close()
    print "Close Socket"

ListenServer()
```

Server :

```
from netaddr import IPAddress
import socket
import sys
import ipaddress
import time


def FindAgent():
    PORT = 50007          # Port use to find Agent

    #Find broadcast address

    """IPAddress("255.255.255.0").netmask_bits()        #Convert Subnet Mask to Prefix Length, Result is 24"""
    try :
        HOST = str(ipaddress.ip_network(u'192.168.10.0/24')[-1])
    except ValueError as e :
        """e = sys.exc_info()[0]  # Find Exception you need"""
        print e

    # UDP client
    MESSAGE = "Authen"
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    for x in range(0,2):
        sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (HOST, PORT))


def ListenClient():
    # Listen Client sent data
    HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    PORT = 50008
    # TCP socket

    # Create Socket
    print "Create Socket"
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except socket.error, e:
        print "Error creating socket: %s" %e
        sys.exit(1)

    # Bind
    print "Bind"
    try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error, e:
        print "Error bind: %s" %e
        sys.exit(1)

    # Listen
    print "Listen"
    try:
        s.listen(10)
    except socket.error, e:
        print "Error listen: %s" %e
        sys.exit(1)

    # Accept data from client
    print "Accept data from client"
    try:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        data = s.recv(1024)
    except socket.error, e:
        print "Error listen: %s" %e
        sys.exit(1)

    print data
    s.close()

FindAgent()
ListenClient()
```

Error on Server :

```
Create Socket
Bind
Listen
Accept data from client
Error listen: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
[Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Win7_Lab\Desktop\Server.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Win7_Lab\Desktop]
[path: C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\]
```

Without the line **data = s.recv(1024)** on Server, it working fine. But with it, the error show up. Can anybody please tell me why it happen ?

Comment: When a server socket accepts a connection from a client, all communication with that particular client goes through the socket returned by `.accept()` (`conn` in your case), NOT the original server socket.

Comment: Thanks  jasonharper, you right. Goodday sir !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash come from `s.recv(1024)` as you said it's because the recieve (`.recv()`) methode on your server need to be called on the client connection.

Follow this example : [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example)

Server file :

```
conn, addr = s.accept()
data = conn.recv(1024)
```

Client file :

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
data = s.recv(1024)
```

As you see the client recieve data from socket (server).
And server recieve data from client connection.

Hope that was usefull.

> Edit add some examples links.

You can find what you want in these tutorial:

- [How to use socket](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html)
- [How to create server with socket and select](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html)
- [Example client server giving time](https://github.com/antoineFrau/td-reseau)
- [Example chat client server](https://github.com/antoineFrau/python-chat)

Comment: You right. It solve my problem. But if i want to receive data from multi client. How i classify each client ?

Comment: Glad this helped you. Take a look to the edit of the response.