# Vague Error With conn.recv(1024) When Using Sockets And Threading

Tags: python, sockets

Good evening,

I am trying to make a basic implementation of the clients-to-server model using sockets.

Basically, I want the client to retrieve a small piece of information (IE: MESSAGE key) to the server. To accomplish this, I've used threading.

When the client sends the request to receive the info, there is no error on the client side.

However, the server sends an error

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stock\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Stock\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "server.py", line 40, in listeningForRetriever
    dataBytes = conn.recv(1024)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

After doing some research, this thread seemed pretty relevant, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49289545/6902431, but I had already implemented the suggested fixes.

server.py

```
import socket
import threading
from Utility import *

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
PORT_A = 22221
PORT_B = 22222
PORT_C = 22223

bank = {'me':'you'}

def listeningForRetriever():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT_B))
        s.listen()
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            while True:
                dataBytes = conn.recv(1024)
                dataString = bytesToString(dataBytes)
                try:
                    retrievedValueBytes = bytesToString(bank[cleanGET(dataString)])
                    print(f"Value: {retrievedValueBytes} has been retrieved with Key {cleanGET(dataString)}")
                    conn.sendall(retrievedValueBytes)
                except:
                    print("SERVER: Errored out")
                    conn.sendall(stringToBytes("ERROR! Value retrieval for command: " + dataString + " doesn't exist!"))

retrieverThread = threading.Thread(target=listeningForRetriever)

retrieverThread.start()
```

retriever.py

```
#Retrieves values from server using keys
#retriever.py --key=username

import sys
import socket
from Utility import *

# total arguments
n = len(sys.argv)
print("Total arguments passed:", n)

# Arguments passed
print("\nName of Python script:", sys.argv[0])

print("\nArguments passed:", end = " ")

key = ''
value = ''

for i in range(1, n):
    print(sys.argv[i], end = " ")
    if '--key=' in sys.argv[i]:
        data = sys.argv[i].replace('--key=','')
        key = data

print()

if key == '':
    print("ERROR! Invalid syntax.")
    print("Try something like: Bob.py --key=username")
else:
    print(f"Key: {key} {type(key)}")

    #TODO: Send key to storage of server
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
    PORT = 22222        # The port used by the server

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        s.sendall(stringToBytes("GET key"+"="+key))
        print("DEBUG 1")
        value = s.recv(1024)
        print("DEBUG 2")
        print(f"Retrieved Value: {value}")





    print(f"Value Retrieved: {value}")
s.close()
```

What am I overlooking/misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could (more or less...) reproduce and fix. But I may be wrong, because your code uses an `Utility` module that you failed to show so I could only guess from the names what `bytesToString`, `stringToBytes` and `cleanGET` were supposed to do.

First there is a misunderstanding about how TCP actually behaves. It is a streaming protocol, that guarantees that all sent bytes will be received an in same order. But there is no guarantee on the packets themselves: they may be splitted and/or reassembled by the network. So you must use a higher level way to delimit a message. It does not exhibit any problem here because short packets are often left unmodified, but the protocol does not guarantee that so you could experience weird errors later. Here as you send a single message, you could shut down the socket to signal the end of the message: the receiver will see a 0 size packet at that point.

Next (and the actual cause of your problem), you loop *after* accepting a connection. So you get a message, successfully process it, read again on a socket that will be closed by the peer and get a 0 size byte string. It probably causes a key error when looking in the `bank` dict, but you silently swallow that error message (which is **BAD**), so you try to write on a socket closed by the peer, which causes the connection to be aborted. And finally on next `recv` you get the error that you see.

What you should have learned from that:

- never ever use a silent `try: ... except: ...` that swallows any exception without letting you know what has happened. Always limit the filtered exception to the smaller expected set, or (at least and at dev time) display the caught exception to make sure you have not inadvertently caught an unwanted one.
- use a higher level protocol to delimit messages on TCP

Now for the fixes:

retriever.py

```
...
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(stringToBytes("GET key"+"="+key))
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)   # signals the end of the message
    print("DEBUG 1")
    ...
```

server.py

```
    ...
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        # read until the end of a message signaled by a 0 size packet
        dataBytes = b''
        while True:
            b = conn.recv(1024)
            if len(b) == 0:
                break
            dataBytes += b
        dataString = bytesToString(dataBytes)
        try:
            retrievedValueBytes = stringToBytes(bank[cleanGET(dataString)])
            print(f"Value: {retrievedValueBytes} has been retrieved with Key {cleanGET(dataString)}")
            conn.sendall(retrievedValueBytes)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("SERVER: Errored out")
            conn.sendall(stringToBytes("ERROR! Value retrieval for command: " + dataString + " doesn't exist!"))
        ...
```

Here the thread stops after one single message. If you want the server to be able to accept many clients, you can loop over `accept`:

```
    s.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I feel like your answer really helped me with the gaps in my understanding as well as addressed some bad practices I'd been doing. Fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

Your server is coded to listen in a loop (while True / conn.recv), but your
client only listens once, then exits, which closes the connection.

So the message on the server side is actually not vague at all, it's perfectly to
the point: it's telling you that the connection has been closed. It has indeed,
by the client.

(To be very specific, your retriever code uses a socket as a context manager,
meaning that when you exit the 'with' bock, the socket gets automatically
closed - you can remove the s.close() call, BTW)

Your code works fine, you should be getting the data back (I did, but your post
doesn't say anything about that). The only thing missing is the exception
handling on the server side to gracefully handle the client disconnection.